# bash adb command not found via terminal for OUYA driver setup?

Tags: android, bash, ouya

I'm trying to setup the OUYA driver on my Mac OS (Maverick) and I'm getting bash-3.2$ command not found when I type in the commands to root the pointer / install the driver. I'm following this video tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5LSBiNfMq8A and have followed everything correctly but for some odd reason once I try to type in adb after bash-3.2$ comes up, not works. What am I doing wrong? I've looked all over the internet and on the OUYA forums and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my terminal commands.

```
Matthews-Mac-mini:~ mycomp$ vi ~/.bashrc
Matthews-Mac-mini:~ mycomp$ adb
-bash: adb: command not found
Matthews-Mac-mini:~ mycomp$ bash
bash-3.2$ adb kill-server
bash: adb: command not found
bash-3.2$
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `adb` tool is part of the Android SDK. If `ANDROID_HOME` is set to the directory where you put the Android SDK on your Mac, then you need to add `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to `PATH` , like this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/users/myname/android  # or wherever you put the Android SDK
PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Comment: So the directory I have it setup in is /users/myname/android. I'm not really sure by what you mean by ANDROID_HOME.

Comment: I mean, set `ANDROID_HOME` to `/users/myname/android`. It's a good convention, and some tools that use the Android SDK expect this variable to be set anyway. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using a Mac that couldn't find were to run the command in the terminal it is located at

```
Users/YourUserName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

(if you type `ls` you should see a file called `"adb"`) You'll type `./adb kill-server` that should do it.

Apparently the `./` is the full path to the executable.

Comment: This helped me but still didn´t get it to work. I changed it to another USB port and voilá, my device appeared .... It is strange because the previous USB port seems to work fine for some other devices ...